# How do I delete Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, internet-explorer-11

How do I delete Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge? When I go to settings, I didn't see any apps. I looked at where it says systems and there were none there either. Nothing was there that looked like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaPrm.png)

Answer (score 2):

These utilities can never be fully deleted, only disabled, as they use Windows
components. Microsoft will soon replace Edge by a Chromium version, so perhaps
it is not worth disabling.

**Disable Microsoft Edge**

- Go to `C:\Windows\SystemApps`
- Locate the Microsoft Edge folder. Mine is `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`
- Save the name of the folder, as you will need it to re-enable the app
- Rename the folder
- Click Continue if asked.

To re-enable Edge, give the folder its original name back.

**Disable Internet Explorer 11**

- Go to *Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features*
- Click *Turn Windows features on or off*
- Clear the checkbox next to "Internet Explorer 11"
- Click Yes and OK and reboot.

[image]